# Jumping off of a cliff into water - survival tips

Tags: survival, water

Another scary scenario:

Let's say you're in a situation where you have to jump off of a cliff into the water to survive.

The cliff is at least 100 feet high.

What would be the best way to survive the fall and ensure that you don't break a thousand bones when landing in the water?

Dive head first and break water with hands? Cannonball? Or do a pencil drop and break water with feet?

Seems like any one of these would end up hurting quite a bit and might compromise being able to swim away afterwards.

Comment: I'll bet anything you have that you won't break *a thousand* bones.  210, tops.

Comment: you win the bet

Comment: Make sure the water is deep enough first?  If you don't know that, it's a diceroll no matter what.

Comment: I wonder whether throwing a boulder into the water to break the surface first would make any difference.

Comment: @Hermann:  It would definitely help if the water was frozen, but otherwise I'm not so sure.

Comment: @TobySpeight It's an expression, a type of exaggeration. We all understand that humans don't really have a thousand bones. There was no need to comment.

Comment: @TobySpeight You might start the impact with that many bones, sure.  But during the course of the impact, the number of independent pieces of bone in your body could increase *dramatically*.

Comment: @TobySpeight Did you land right on top of the 4-5 previous jumpers?

Comment: [How not to do it: dødsing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4rrctxmxfU)

Comment: @Hermann For liquid water, I think the object would pose a greater risk than benefit. You could get hurt worse by hitting the boulder. Also, I think I recall a test done for this at one time, by Myth Busters with a crash dummy I think.

Comment: @Loduwijk Indeed, they looked into it (https://mythresults.com/episode5). They used a hammer (way smaller than what I had in mind) and it was not particularly well executed (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCSQExxWulU). I should probably ask a new question about this over at physics.se.

Comment: Mad magazine's classic: https://usualgangofidiots.tumblr.com/image/177496388660

Comment: @TobySpeight, Depends how you define 'bones'. It wouldn't be grossly out of order to suggest that once you've broken 1 bone that you've now got 211 bones... But yeah ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: A person called @Graham talking about a dramatic increase of a number is just perfect.

Comment: [206 bones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_skeleton), for us pedants ;-)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

There's an abandoned quarry near me where local kids used to jump off the topmost cliff edge, 100 feet up, every summer.  When done properly it is survivable without injury.

**You have to break the surface tension with a part of your body that can take the blow, and you have to keep all your muscles clenched and your body absolutely rigid, and you have to hit absolutely perpendicular to the surface.**

**If you do it wrong, you are likely to be knocked unconscious and drowned.**

I do it head first, which means keeping the hands locked together in a double fist, elbows and shoulders locked and rigid, hands directly between the top of head and the water, spine absolutely straight.  Do not bend your neck to try to look at the water!

If your arms are not locked and rigid your fists will hit your head and knock you unconscious or your arms will be ripped back and dislocated and the water will knock you unconscious.

It can also be done feet first, which means keeping the knees locked, all muscles in legs, thighs and butt absolutely clenched rigid, heels sharply pointed down, looking straight ahead and hitting the water again perpendicular to the surface.

If your feet spread you will crush your genitalia, and if you're male will require medical treatment.  If you do not clench your butt you may intake water with damaging force. If you look down you will get smacked in the face hard enough to break your nose and possibly knock you out.

I did it wrong once, and hit at an angle instead of perpendicular. Striking the water felt like hitting concrete.  My left arm was ripped backwards, completely dislocating the shoulder.  I was knocked unconscious and concussed.  The rapid compression of my chest ruptured my left lung and my legs were temporarily paralyzed, perhaps by the impact to my spine or skull. Although I survived, my body was permanently damaged by the injury - my left shoulder dislocates more easily than my right, and I have a scar tissue mass in my lung from the haemothorax.

Comment: ouch.  this should probably be the accepted answer.  i am not surprised you have to be very specific in how you land, which is why i didn't go into position much beyond my choice of feet first, always.  where are your arms if you are feet first?  at your side?  above your head?  i get the impression that from extreme heights you can't do any tricks to minimize how deep you go.

Comment: *my left shoulder dislocates more easily than my right*  :-o  FWIW, my father used to tell stories about jumping off bridges in New York city when he was young.  Apparently holding a blanket or sheet in both hands over your head helps to ensure a vertical, feet-first entry into the water.  Even a shirt would probably help some.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I go head first, but I believe that if your hands are at your side when jumping feet first, you have to have them flat and rigid, fingers pointed down and tight against your body.  You need to enter the water through the point where you've already broken the surface tension.

Comment: If you go headfirst don't you also risk smashing your head on a rock or jamming your head into your neck and seriously hurting the vertebrae in it? Seems like feet first would be a lot safer unless you were 100% sure that the water was very deep and had nothing solid in it you could hit.

Comment: @StephenMIrving head first or feet first if you hit rocks from that far up your spine is a goner and there's very little that can be done to save you. If you aren't sure of a clear landing zone, don't jump it's not worth the risk

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica from my own experience as a lifeguard and swim instructor, it's easier to flatten out your entry going feet first than head first. Feet first once you're in the water you can push your feet out parallel to the water surface to limit your depth

Comment: @AndrewHenle - Interesting. I wonder did he hold it like a parachute (i.e all 4 corners) or just from one edge, so it flapped like a flag? In my experience as a young and stupid kid, jumping off our house with a tarp held like a parachute, was that it would cause you to swing backwards and forwards as it spilled air out the edges. Apparently this is why those round WW2 parachutes had holes in the top - it just slows the air rather than capturing and causing you to swing.

Comment: Your comments/wording seem to indicate you still do these dives even after your injury. Do I have that correct?

Comment: @bob1 Per the stories I remember, the sheet/blanket was held like a flag so it flapped.

Comment: @BKlassen that sounds right! thank you for the response.

Comment: In one of your comments you mention "surface tension", but the property of water that changes upon the splash is actually rather "compressibility".  It is because a whirlwind of water and light, soft air bubbles is easier to displace than unbroken incompressible water.  If surface tension was also a factor, you'd notice differences between going in wet, dry, and waxed (wet skin would make immersion easier, and dry or waxed skin would make walking on water easier).

Comment: Oooph, too real! I've done some jumps, but maybe only 20m, feet first. No rush to do any more, but your recollection is giving me a weird adrenaline/cortisol rush that accompanied the jumps themselves

Comment: ouch. sounds like it's not worth the bother with that kind of risk. Especially given the brain injury bit.

Comment: I think @JirkaHanika is right that this is not about surface tension. But softening the water by introducing some air is I think just a part of the story. When you enter the water you need to move the water out of your way. Entering vertically means presenting the smallest area of your body to the water surface, so you're moving the water out of your way gradually instead of all at once. This spreads the the impact energy over a longer time period and reduces the sudden deceleration you experience.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman - I agree with you, and even more with the answer's focus in keeping your body super carefully in one of two "maintainable" positions.  I was only commenting on the surface tension detail in connection with the finger tips when going feet first, and not on the whole process.  I may be easily be wrong even in that previous comment of mine and the need to keep palms straight and pressed onto the body may simply be a way of strengthening the arms, as if by the side of the body acting as a splint.  But I think that the compressibility change helps, too.

Answer (score 23):

Feet first is always best - you might break your legs if you hit the bottom, but at least you won't break your back, neck, or be knocked unconscious - all of which can kill you, either through the damage to the spine or through drowning.

I would aim to jump in angled away from the cliff (i.e. body not totally vertical), arms across chest or covering mouth/nose (not holding nose - you'll break your nose when the water shoves your arm), and aim to use the momentum of the jump to cause you to swing rapidly under the water dissipating the momentum, so as to not go too deep. See rather crude drawing I just whipped up:

[image: Exaggerated jumping image]

Basically the jump should look like the [out-of-helicopter jumps that you might see the Coast-guard do](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uiXO0N3onU8), such as the one in the linked Youtube video.

Edited to add: there's some physics on the jump [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9059/jumping-into-water), and within that the top answer indicates that they were trained to survive a fall from 100 ft (30 metre; aircraft carrier height), not that they had to do it. Other answers indicate that the max survivable seems to be about 250 feet (75 metre) into water.

Also edited to add: It's not as easy as you might think - in my experience, if you do it right, making yourself as hydrodynamic as possible, a simple jump off the side of a pool (~ 1 ft / 30 cm) into the water can get you to the bottom of a dive pool (~20 ft / 6 metre) pretty handily, so there's a real risk of breaking bones jumping from any substantial height into water, even if it is quite deep.

Comment: That helicopter jump is only about 5m (15') based on the fact they're falling for roughly 1 second.  It may still be a good model, but they're also wearing fins which may affect how they have to hold their feet, and also means they won't go as deep

Comment: Yes, but the basic jump will be very similar in terms of jumping from height into (deep) water. Obviously the OP won't be holding their helmet onto their head, but in general, elbows tight to sides, feet first, cover mouth/nose.

Comment: Important things to keep in mind when jumping like this from heights, keep your arms crossed with elbows in tight to your body, legs crossed with toes pointed, and [clench your butt](https://1000waystodie.fandom.com/wiki/Water_Logged)

Comment: @Malco ^ Hahahaha omg

Comment: Does this answer (including numbers specified) vary any based on one's weight and size?

Comment: From a physics perspective a larger person will have greater momentum (mass x velocity) - so yes. Basically from 30 m, you'll be going at 87 km/h/54 mph - that's very fast and water is very hard at these speeds, so the more stream-lined you can make yourself, the better - a fat person will have greater spread than a skinny one, so they'll most likely get hurt more is my guess.

Comment: @bob1 Not to be insensitive, but won't they also have relatively more cushion to soften the blow?

Comment: @Mast - maybe but that cushion is still inside their body so the forces don't get lost and transferred like they would in a kevlar vest, perhaps less transferred to delicate internal organs. In this case it's about cross-sectional area - the bigger this is (up to a point), the more it's going to hurt as the force is transferred over a greater area in a shorter space of time. In addition - that "cushion" is contained in skin - with pain receptors and all...it's going to hurt!

Comment: Oh, this is definitely going to hurt. But I imagine major bruising is preferred over intestine ruptures and breaking bones.

Comment: @Mast, yes, but all things being equal in terms of posture and mass, a skinny person would have a more stream-lined shape, so the transfer of energy will take longer and result in less pressure (force/area) on the body. At least that's my, admittedly limited, understanding of the physics.

Comment: this is taught with lifeguarding as well for deep water entries

Comment: I think you made up this whole answer. It's not based on any evidence or research, just your own gut feeling.

Comment: @theonlygusti - well, I did do some research before answering, and synthesized the results, so a sort of making-it-up. That's how these sorts of things work in general. Other than going out and getting people to jump off cliffs in different manners under scientific observation, how else do you expect people to answer these questions?

Answer (score 16):

Well, first thing first, 100' (30 metre) is likely not to end well for you.  So really the question stops being valid way before that.

Second, if you've ever spent anytime diving and had the pleasure of a bellyflop, you know you don't want to put yourself into any kind of uncontrolled tumble, and that means minimizing your rotation from your starting position.  Feet first on land, feet first in the water, would be my thinking.  Of course, if you know what you are doing diving then you can certainly aim for a cleaner jump and go in head first.  That's what the Acapulco cliff divers do.  But they wouldn't be asking this question.

Third, even if you know how to dive in cleanly, you don't necessarily know how deep the water is at the bottom of the cliff.  That means that diving head first puts you at extra risk - better to hit the bottom with your feet than your head.

**So, don't do this.  Don't jump off cliffs without knowing exactly what's underneath.  Ever.**

I personally know one guy who is paralyzed for life because he forgot how much of a tidal difference there is where I live.  And just saw a plaque [commemorating someone who died](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siwash_Rock) for the same reason yesterday (there are 2 plaques there, Wiki's is about the legend).

If I had to jump, I know I would jump feet first however.  I am not that comfortable doing head first, even though I have done it up to about 20-25' (6-8 metre) high.  If you're a beginner at high jumps, head first is just that much trickier to get right and in any case it leaves you more at risk from hitting your head.

From [wikipedia, High Diving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_diving):

> **Health implications**
>   Some research suggests that the impact associated with high diving could have negative effects on the joints and muscles of athletes. To avoid injury to their arms upon impact with the water, divers from significant heights may enter the water feet first.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion - head first carries the risk of undercommitting and hitting the water badly.  But I'm not sure there's much more risk if well executed: if you hit the bottom feet first you can still break your back and then drown while conscious (worst case of course).

Comment: gotta disagree.  first, you bleed speed way quicker landing on your feet in a sitting position than in a clean head first dive.  you can probably dive from 10' feet and have minimal impact in 6-8' of water, esp if you put out your arms.  second, *any* hit to your head/neck is dangerous, while our feet are made for landing on.  I thought of the "clean dive" from heights pushing for head first from very high and with a trained athlete, but the wikipedia page isn't all that supportive of the concept either, see my quote.

Comment: If you land on your backside in a sitting position - a small error if you're aiming for feet first - you'll do yourself a lot of damage.  [Here's a paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2916780) on damage from landing on the feet (not specifically on water)

Comment: I don't want to be unpleasant here, but suggesting that head first is safer, or not more risky, than feet first, **unless you absolutely know 200% what the depth is and that you can clear it**, is just totally  irresponsible, no matter how you present it.  That's my opinion and you are welcome to yours, but I wanted to put that on the record because I consider it to be a core safety concern.  Now, on extreme heights, with skilled divers other considerations may come into play, see Medievalist's answer.  But not 99% of the rest of the time and certainly not for casual divers.

Comment: assuming you're replying to me, read what I wrote first. My words, added emphasis: "not sure there's *much* more risk" (to head first) . I was highlighting the very real risks of serious injury or death from landing feet first, that you at least initially brushed off, and not recommending a head first entry. I stand by that, and I'm out of here

Answer (score 7):

Feet first. This has been well covered in other answers.

Keep your body nice and straight, use your abs to support yourself, point your toes. All the things that competitive divers do to make less splash will also make your entry into the water easier. Take a deep breath, you will need it (about 2.5 seconds of fall time, plus however long it takes you to get back to the surface!).

However, once you enter the water you should do a modified "save". Basically the opposite of above, after you enter the water you make your surface area larger so that you stop going down as quickly as possible. There are complicated techniques for doing this in competitive diving to create the appearance of a perfectly straight dive, but you don't care about that so yours can be much simpler. 1) Wait until you are fully in the water. 2) Go limp. Let your legs bend up a little, almost like you're sitting in a chair. 3) When you feel comfortable with your speed relative to the strength of your arms, use your arms to do a flip under water.

Then kick kick kick back to the surface, you will be low on air.

(I used to do not-very-competitive diving, and the same dive with and without a save was the difference between landing hard enough to stub a toe on the bottom of 13 feet, vs barely going below the surface.)

Comment: Is “_wait_ until you are fully in the water” really how it works? It seems that this would go way too fast to actually _react_ to the impact.

Comment: @leftaroundabout In competitive diving, you save literally at the point where you're entering the water, to make your dive appear straighter (your legs would tip over from rotation, but instead you take the rotation into your upper body and leave your legs straight up). I don't think that's doable from this height, but I wanted to point out that you shouldn't even try it since if you go too early bad things happen. Likewise, a competitive save would swim with the arms right away, but not a good idea from that height--just wait until you've slowed down a bit.

Answer (score 6):

XY-question frame challenge.

**The only way to win the game is to not play.**

**If** you were to be jumping in, then the other answers give insightful food for thought. But that's a huge, colossal **if**, especially given your use case. So here comes the party-pooper...

As long as you are even moderately well prepared I would be willing to bet a lot of money that the odds of "I'm in a The Great Outdoors survival situation where I need to jump 100 feet off a cliff into water" are very slim. I think you're more likely to get struck by lightning on a clear day where no signs of lightning were present (supposedly, that happens).

Originally I was much stronger in my wording. But thanks to @BlackThorn for pointing out there are use cases similar enough to what the question asks for that they should also be seriously considered. BlackThorn wrote:

> Fire on a cruise ship, fire on an aircraft carrier, friend falls off
> of cliff and you want to rescue him before he drowns (and you jump
> because you are confident you can survive the fall to rescue him). The
> last example literally happened to a friend of mine with an 80 foot
> cliff and he saved his life, holding his friends face above the water
> until paramedics arrived.

### Ship Fire

Even if there is a fire on a ship, that doesn't mean you're likely to be forced to jump from the top, but that could be a possibility. If you are on a tall ship and concerned about fire safety, a safer strategy would be to review the ship's fire evacuation routes and procedures. In case of fire, a smart evacuation is better than a frantic high jump.

### Cliff Rescue

In the case of a friend falling from a cliff, again, that does not automatically mean someone should immediately jump in after them, especially if you don't know the safety situation at the bottom. In all emergency rescue situations, you need to ensure your own safety as well otherwise you endanger both yourself and the other person.

If a friend falls from a cliff, **do not** immediately jump over after them. As quickly as you can, scan the bottom for safety hazards. Wait a second to see what is happening to the person who fell as well.

I am happy for BlackThorn's friend that the outcome was favorable. However, this anecdotal evidence does not mean you should throw logic to the wind, and hopefully the heroic friend performed the rescue safely.

An 80 to 100 foot fall takes between 2-3 seconds according to a quick Google query. Human reaction time means that a rescuer is likely to be at least a second or two behind to begin with. At that point you might as well wait the 1 second to see how the victim lands since they might not even need rescuing. And if you are wearing any very cumbersome clothing you should remove it first: I know some of my boots would make it impossible to perform a water rescue in, so taking even 10 seconds to remove them would be better than jumping in with them on.

So work quickly to save the person, but don't rush to the point of making the situation worse. The old "hurry up and wait."

It has also happened that people jumping from heights into water have landed on a person at the bottom and killed them. It would be a tragic accident if a heroic effort to save someone who would not have died anyway led to both the victim and the hero dying together in vain.

If you are absolutely sure that this is actually necessary, then jump in like a rigid vertical pencil.

### Realistic possibility of survival jump

The "jump off a cliff to survive" trope is exciting but not realistic.

Maybe this question was inspired by a scene I've heard about where Bear Grylls supposedly did something similar and made some people thing it was a reasonable survival tactic. I haven't seen the scene myself.

This use case is simply not realistic and is a dangerous view of wilderness survival. Even if you create a highly contrived scenario where you make it seem like this is the best option, I would still take my chances sitting tight and doing my best on the high ground. Your survival odds are likely higher.

Even if you are severely dehydrated and need the water at the bottom of the cliff, in that case I still might stay up top. To be so dehydrated that you would risk the jump means you're probably also so dehydrated that you 1) aren't thinking as clearly and are more likely to make bad choices, and 2) lack the coordination and strength to perform the jump technique well and will have even higher odds of severe injury or death.

### "I still want to prepare for this rare situation anyway!"

Ok, then here's what you can do that will benefit you way more. An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure.

**Predators:** To deal with predators bring defenses and learn to use them. Bear spray, knowledge of local predators and how to remain safe around them, defensible positions (ie: don't put yourself between a cliff and predator to begin with).

**Forest fire:** You might still be at risk at the bottom of the cliff. You might also make it harder for rescuers to find or reach you by making such a change to your location.

**Wilderness Survival:** Everyone needs to get the idea out of their head that such risky actions are a part of real wilderness survival training. If you're in a wilderness survival situation, you need to avoid such risks at all costs.

Out of all the rare cases where you might otherwise be tempted to jump, in most of them you would probably be better served by bringing bear spray and bringing an emergency locator beacon to signal for help and let rescuers know your location.

Climbed up a rock face and dropped your gear? Activate your beacon. Realize a forest fire is nearby? Activate your beacon. Being hunted or attacked? Active your bear spray. Any other situation where you don't have to jump *right this second*? Active your beacon.

"But what if the beacon fails?" That's possible, sure, but what are the odds that will happen coinciding with an animal attack coinciding with a cliff-you-animal sandwich, coinciding with survivable water at the bottom of it? Not convinced? Get a second beacon as a back up.

Think ahead for situation-specific emergency backups, like an emergency waist pack with an extra rope and/or beacon. Similarly, if this is a concern plan for it before a trip where you're around cliffs: What could go wrong, and how could I mitigate that so I wouldn't have to jump?

### Summary

**Don't jump!** Just bring defenses and a beacon and plan ahead, as mitigating the situation beforehand has much higher chance of success than dealing with it after.

If you do somehow manage to have no choice at all but to jump, and you decide to jump despite your terrible luck at this point, then look to the other answers and pencil drop in straight and rigid.

Comment: Fire on a cruise ship, fire on an aircraft carrier, friend falls off of cliff and you want to rescue him before he drowns (and you jump because you are confident you can survive the fall to rescue him). The last example literally happened to a friend of mine with an 80 foot cliff and he saved his life, holding his friends face above the water until paramedics arrived.

Comment: appreciate the response but however unlikely the situation may seem, im just curious to know what would be the best way to survive a fall like that

Comment: @mph85 Oh, I agree. And I'm actually glad you asked, as I think it's a great question. And I'm glad to have read the other answers that answered you more directly. I think it's good information, and you and I are better off for having read it. But because it's so unlikely, I think that reading those answers is all I need to do to prepare; it's a cost-benefit trade off thing. And I still recommend more time and effort spent on the other things I mentioned even to prepare for this situation.

Comment: Aircraft carriers and many cruise ships have decks that are actually quite a bit taller than 100 ft above the water, even over 200 ft. If I worked on either type of vessel, I would certainly want to prepare for the event that I would need to find quick egress overboard. You are right to suggest that you ought to avoid jumping if at all possible, but I think you significantly underestimate the situations that might require such action.

Comment: @BlackThorn As I said, I was answering the question very directly: jump from a cliff. Not jump from a ship. I think that my original answer was right on if you take a very narrow look at OP's specific use case and put blinders on to all similar situations, but taking a wider view now (thanks to you) I realize the jump information is even more useful. Check out the edit I just finished. It removes the extremely strong "1-in-10B" type phrasing, includes the wider point of view, and I think is a better answer now.

Answer (score 2):

The New Yorker has an interesting and sad [article on people jumping off the Golden Gate Bridge](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2003/10/13/jumpers).  According to the article:

> The rare survivors always hit feet first, and at a slight angle.

Answer (score -1):

I just want to add one thing the other answers didn't emphasize enough : keep your arms along your body !

Don't put them above your head, don't spread them like if you were a bird ; keep them close !

If you don't... well, you're just [Strappado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strappado)'ing yourself.

Answer (score -3):

Jump feet first and rotate like a drill. This will slow you down upon entering the water so you dont hit bottom.

Comment: Interesting. Can you actually have this level of control? Would your rotation slow down significantly as you fall? Also, wouldn't the drilling make you go faster? I would think that might provide a mechanism for the water to be displaced more easily or something.

Comment: @Andrew: If you were a trained olympic style diver, you might have this sort of control from a stationary jump, normal people not so much. The real risk here is imparting a tumble and ending up in a posture that is not optimal for entering the water and doing yourself serious injury. I doubt that the rotational speed that anyone could impart would be enough to have anything other than a minor effect.

Comment: Every time I see this answer I picture in my head an anime character taking a running leap off the cliff, momentarily stopping in the air as they begin to spin, then shooting down like a drill. As if it's some kind of fighter-game move or anime DBZ'ish move.